# Is drawing of web button in Imagemagick possible?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Total newbie question about Imagemagick: Is making this kind of button:

[Button with a metal ring](http://mygimptutorial.com/round-web-20-button-with-a-metal-ring)

from 0 to 100% (without using background or mask images from outside programs like Gimp or Photoshop) even possible?

If it is, does anybody have some quick tips for me?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible but I'd be a lot of work. I would recommend you to create a (background) template, save it and the only overlay the letter with imagemagick.

Comment: I imagine it's a lot of work, but if I learn this the "long - hard way" I will learn more... That way I learned GIMP, Inkscape, Blender, and manny other programs.

10x anyway :)